# Duvida com a query LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

Desenvolvi uma função que busca no banco um cliente pelo ID:

```
function buscaId ($id,$conexao){
    $resultados= array();
    $query= "select * from cliente where id like '$id%' ";
    $resultado= mysqli_query($conexao,$query);
    while ($resultado_cliente = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
            array_push($resultados, $resultado_cliente);



        }

            return $resultados;
    }
```

Porém, quando digito `"%%" ou "VAZIO "` no "Pesquisar", ele traz todos os clientes do banco.

Como faço para desativar isso? O banco vai ter 7,000 linhas.

Comment: cria uma condição ( `IF` ) na função se `$id` for vazio já retorna ( `return` ) e não executa o resto;

Comment: se é pelo ID porque buscar com like?

Comment: Obrigado arllondias não tem necessidade do LIKE eu tirei e resolveu kkk

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o PDO do php. É mais seguro e apresenta uma maior abstração. E mais, não precisas do ciclo porque a query só retorna um registro. Vai um exemplo.

```
    function buscaId ($conexao, $id)
    {
        $resultados= array();
        $query= "select * from users where id = ?";        
        $stmt = $conexao->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        $rows = $stmt->fetch();

        return $rows;
    }

   $resultado = buscaId($conexao, 1);
   echo 'Id: '.$resultado['id'].' - Nome:' .$resultado['name'] ;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica e o exemplo  Mia  vou tentar aplicar o PDO